# Perform actions based on screen presence (Android JAVA)

Tags: appium, appium-android

Say i have two screens ‘A’ and ‘B’, i want to execute action ‘1’ if screen ‘A’ is shown and action ‘2’ if screen ‘B’ is shown. Initially am checking the screen ‘A’ and ‘B’ presence using the if else statement but didn’t work. here is my code

```
if(screenAisShown()) 
{
button1.click;
} else if(screenBisShown) {
button2.click;
}
```

In the first iteration screen A is shown so the if block executes successfully and in the second iteration screen B is shown but NoSuchElementException thrown for if block and the else if is not executed

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a method **isAScreenDisplayed()** and **isBScreenDisplayed()**.

```
public static boolean isAScreenDisplayed(){
   try{
       return elementOfAScreen.isDisplayed();
   }catch(Exception e){
       return false;
   }
}

public static boolean isBScreenDisplayed(){
   try{
       return elementOfBScreen.isDisplayed();
   }catch(Exception e){
       return false;
   }
}
```

Now you can use if else condition to check which screen is displayed.

```
if(isAScreenDisplayed){
   //do something
}
else if(isBScreenDisplayed){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to verify, you can use `currentActivity` method which return current Screen `Activity` name as a `String`

```
if(driver.currentActivity().equals("Screen1 Activity Name")) 
{   
    // wait for button1 code
    if (button1.isDisplayed())
        button1.click;
} 
else if(driver.currentActivity().equals("Screen2 Activity Name")) {
    // wait for button2 code
    if (button2.isDisplayed())
        button2.click;
}
else{
   syso("Screen 1 OR Screen 2 are not in focus)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately, one of the screen is a custom dialog and doesn't have a screen activity name. i tried 'try catch' block for returning the screen presence and called that method in my test class with 'if else'. this worked for me.